# PDO Wrapper Class - If Connected Check

Tags: php, dependency-injection, constructor, factory

I'm writing a PDO Wrapper as a bit of a learning project and I'm trying to combine it with using dependency injection. My current set up has a factory that will set dependencies. So, for example, I'll have a form class which passes in a couple of objects to output html attributes etc.

I'm wanting to keep it like that but in my factory class, I only want to use one instance of each object, instead of making a new object everytime. An example will probably explain this much better:

```
class Factory {

public static function Form() {

    $html = new Html;
    $form = new Form;
    $form->html = $html;
    return $form;

}

}
```

And my HTML class:

```
class HTML {

// Outputs attributes in the given array
public function attributes($attributes = array()) {

    // Create string of HTML attributes
    foreach($attributes as $key => $attribute):
        $tags .= $key . '=' . $attribute . ' ';
    endforeach;

    return $tags;

}

}
```

So basically, I want to create the HTML object once in the Factory then pass that through to the Form method, which will create the form and allow my access to HTML methods.

I'm assuming I will have to setup a constructor in my Factory that will create the HTML object? The problem I see from that is that everytime I run Factory::Form, the HTML object will be created a new. Is there a simple way around that? i.e. when Factory is used, check to see if an HTML object is created, if so, use the current one.

It's probably very simple but any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is exactly what you mean, but your factory class can accept parameters in `Form()` method, like

```
class Factory {
  public function Form(Html $html = NULL){
    if(is_null($html)){
      $html = new Html();
    }
   // etc.
}
```

And for the other question, in fact your factory class needs no constructor. You need to call the appropriate method only.

EDIT

I haven't realized that your Form method is static. I think you'd need also static field in the class, like:

```
class Factory {
  public static $html;

  public static function Form() {

    if(is_null($this->html)){
       $this->html = new Html;
    }
    $form = new Form;
    $form->html = $this->html;
    return $form;
  }
}
```

Please note that in this solution every object created with this factory will have the same `$html` object!

Comment: I think your edit is definitely what I'm after here. I've done as you've done but put the if statement into another method - then I just call that in the Form method. Works exactly how intended. Thanks for the quick reply!